# Passthrough query in R

Tags: sql, r, odbc, netezza

In SAS I'm used to PROC SQL, that I can use to query the database and return data into SAS, or execute SQL code in database. For example, from SAS I can use PROC SQL to run a passthrough query to create a new table on my database from another table on the database.

```
proc sql;
connect to netezza ( SERVER=X DATABASE=Z  AUTHDOMAIN="Y");
execute
(
create table B as
select * from A

)
by netezza
;
quit;
```

In R I'm able to connect and query a database using RODBC and some code like:

```
connect1 <- odbcConnect("NZ",believeNRows=FALSE) 

query1 <- "SELECT * FROM A"

df_imp <- sqlQuery(connect1, query1)
```

But how do I go about doing something similar to the SAS code above?

Comment: Maybe you'll find your answer in the dplyr package. Take a look at: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same `sqlQuery`:

```
sqlQuery(connect1, "CREATE TABLE b as SELECT * FROM a")
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that and had failed. For some reason I must have done it wrong, because when I re-tried this morning it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

IBM provides several interfaces to use R with Netezza, to include running R within the appliance.

These are provided for free under GPL. Originally it was only available via Revolution for a fee, but that changed over 1 year ago.

You must register with IBM Developerworks (www.ibm.com/developerworks).

Once registered you can download the software and installation directions.

See http://ibm.co/XOC1q3

On this wiki (under the How To section), there are several documents and labs regarding the use of R with Netezza.